# Homotopy equivalent Kan complexes have homotopy equivalent "path spaces"

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Fun}{Fun}$
Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a homotopy equivalence of Kan complexes (in the sense of [Definition 3.1.6.1.](https://kerodon.net/tag/00U2) in Kerodon), with a homotopy inverse $g\colon Y\to X$. I want to show that the induced map $f^*\colon\Fun(\Delta^1, X)\to\Fun(\Delta^1, Y)$ is a homotopy equivalence (the $\infty$-category of functors is defined in [Construction 1.4.3.1.](https://kerodon.net/tag/0060)).

I was thinking of applying [Proposition 3.2.9.1.](https://kerodon.net/tag/00XC) to

[image]

but I'm unsure how to show that the fibers are homotopy equivalent.

Alternatively, I was thinking that for every 0-simplex $\alpha\colon\Delta^1\to X$ we get the $\Lambda^3_1$ horn

[image]

so we can fill its bottom face to get a homotopy $gf\alpha\simeq\alpha$, but I don't know how to extend this "pointwise" homotopy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ is any simplicial set, then $\mathrm{Fun}(S,X)$ and $\mathrm{Fun}(S,Y)$ are both Kan complexes. Furthermore, if $h\colon X\times\Delta^1\to X$ is a simplicial homotopy between the identity and $g\circ f$ and the identity, then the composition
$$\mathrm{Fun}(S,X)\times\Delta^1\to \mathrm{Fun}(S,X\times\Delta^1)\xrightarrow{h_\ast}\mathrm{Fun}(S,X)$$
is a simplicial homotopy from $(g\circ f)_\ast = g_\ast\circ f_\ast$ and the identity. Here the undecorated arrow is the adjoint of
$$\mathrm{Fun}(S,X)\times\Delta^1\times S\cong \mathrm{Fun}(S,X)\times S\times\Delta^1\xrightarrow{\mathrm{ev}\times \mathrm{id}_{\Delta^1}} X\times\Delta^1.$$
The same argument shows that $f_\ast\circ g_\ast$ is homotopic to the identity of $\mathrm{Fun}(S,Y).$

Comment: So simple! Thank you :)